# HttpRequestMessage client MVC Web API Method Parameter

Tags: parameters, asp.net-web-api

I have the following class

```
public class RegisterExternalBindingModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string ExternalAccessToken { get; set; }

    public string Provider { get; set; }
}
```

The following WebAPI Method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("LoginExternal")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
```

I am using the following code to call the Web API Method

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(ConfigurationSettings.AppExternalAccessTokenUrl));
var requestParam = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { UserName = "Dan", ExternalAccessToken = googleAccessToken, Provider = "google" });
request.Content = new HttpStringContent(Uri.EscapeDataString(requestParam));

if (request.Content.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Type"))
{
    request.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
}
request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
```

However when the Web API Method LoginExternal executes the parameter object itself is created but the individual values are null.  Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From how it looks you need to force WebAPI to read the model from thw message body:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginExternal([FromBody] RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
```

If this doesn't do the trick you should also mark it with the HttpPost verb:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginExternal([FromBody] RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
```

Comment: Does the HttpGet method allow the reading of content from the body?

Comment: Even though it's not quite 'legal' to add a message body on a HTTP get request from what I recall WebAPI should allow you to read it.

Comment: If you want to respect the RESTfull API design standards then I suggest changing the type to POST.